# When button is pressed, modify other buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Just getting started with SwiftUI so there is probably something straightforward I am missing.

When the "CHECK" button is pressed, I want to change the background color of the button with an index that matches question.correctChoiceIndex, as well as the button selected by the user, if it is not the correct one.

I am not sure how to actually reference the buttons with a function (if that is the best way), and I figured it might be difficult because the buttons are made with the AnswerButton struct.

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let question: Question
   @State var guessedIndex: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Text(question.questionText)
                .padding()
           
                
        VStack {
            ForEach(question.AnswerChoices.indices) {index in
                AnswerButton(text: question.AnswerChoices[index]){ 
                    guessedIndex = index
                }
                .border(selectChoice(at: index), width: 4)
            }}
            Spacer()
            Text("Answer feedback")
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        HStack{
            Button("CHECK") {
               
            }
            .padding()
            Button("NEXT") {
                /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/ /*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
            }
            .padding()
        }
        }
        
    }
    func selectChoice(at buttonIndex: Int) -> Color {
        if buttonIndex == guessedIndex {
            return .gray

    }
        else {
            return .clear
        }
    }
    
}


struct AnswerButton: View {
    let text: String
    let onClick: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            onClick()
        }) {
                Text(text)

            }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }

}
               

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(question: Question.AllQuestions[0])
           
        }
    }
}
```

I thought looping through all the buttons in the view and checking their index could work, but it also seems a bit inefficient to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to make some assumptions about the Question, and there are better ways one could structure this, but here's something that works.

This will mark an incorrect answer as red if selected and checked, and will mark the correct answer as green.

You would need to likely disable the buttons or progress after the check as well.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Question {
    let questionText: String
    let answerChoices: [String]
    let correctAnswerIndex: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let question: Question
    @State var guessedIndex: Int? = nil
    @State var didCheck = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(question.questionText)
                .padding()
            
            ForEach(0 ..< question.answerChoices.count) { index in
                let answer = question.answerChoices[index]
                AnswerButton(text: answer,
                             isCorrectAnswer: index == question.correctAnswerIndex,
                             didCheck: didCheck,
                             isSelected: index == guessedIndex) {
                    guessedIndex = index
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("Answer feedback")
                .padding()
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Button("CHECK") {
                    didCheck = true
                }
                .padding()
                Button("NEXT") {
                    
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}


struct AnswerButton: View {
    
    let text: String
    let isCorrectAnswer: Bool
    let didCheck: Bool
    let isSelected: Bool
    let onClick: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(text, action: onClick)
            .padding()
            .border(isSelected ? .gray : .clear)
            .background(backgroundColorForCurrentState())
    }
    
    func backgroundColorForCurrentState() -> Color {
        switch (didCheck, isCorrectAnswer, isSelected) {
        case (true, false, true):
            return .red
            
        case (true, true, _):
            return .green
            
        case (_, _, _):
            return .yellow
        }
    }
    
    
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(question: Question(questionText: "examnple",
                                           answerChoices: ["one", "two", "three"],
                                           correctAnswerIndex: 1))
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm getting "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" when I switch out the way you had Question set up with the way I had it setup, in a separate file. It seems to have a problem with the ForEach block, because the error disappears when I comment it out.

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to switch the variable names around.

Comment: Ah, good! I updated the answer to something a little less fancy that the compiler should be happy with too! If this works for you I'd appreciate you accepting the solution! Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you do not reference Buttons etc..., you change the state of the View.

You could try this approach, in keeping with your initial code base.

Note there are many other ways to achieve what you want, in particular
I recommend you have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to manage data in your app:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

```
// for testing
struct Question: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var questionText: String
    var answerChoices: [String]
}
 
struct ContentView: View {
    // for testing
    let question: Question = Question(questionText: "some question", answerChoices: ["answer-1","answer-2","answer-3"])
    
    @State var guessedIndex: Int? = nil
    @State var isCorrect: Bool = false // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Text(question.questionText).padding()
            VStack {
                ForEach(question.answerChoices.indices, id: \.self) { index in  // <-- here
                    AnswerButton(text: question.answerChoices[index]) {
                        guessedIndex = index
                        isCorrect = false // <-- here
                    }
                    .border(guessedIndex == index ? .green : .clear, width: 4) // <-- here
                    .background(guessedIndex == index && isCorrect ? .gray : .yellow) // <-- here
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("Answer feedback").padding()
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Button("CHECK") {
                    checkAnswer() // <-- here
                }.padding()
                Button("NEXT") {
                    
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkAnswer() {
        // some logic here to determine which answer is correct
        isCorrect = guessedIndex == 1  // for testing, answer-2
    }
}

struct AnswerButton: View {
    let text: String
    let onClick: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            onClick()
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```